# Load data into DataGridViewComboBoxColumn VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

Hi I have been banging my head against the wall all day trying to figure this out.

I have a DataGridView that is displaying the results of an SQL Query

The query returns 3 fields: GROUPNUM, GROUPNAME, COACHING

The group fields just have strings in them and they are displaying fine, but the COACHING field is a single character field that will either have a Y or an N in it. For that column I want to have a combobox with Y or N as the items. Here is what I have so far.

dtGroups is a data table that was filled with an SQL data adapter.

```
            dvGroups = dtGroups.DefaultView

            'Set up datagrid view

            With dgvToPopulate

                .Columns.Clear()

                .AutoGenerateColumns = False
                .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
                .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

                .DataSource = dtGroups

                With .Columns

                    Dim groupNumColumn, groupNameColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

                    With groupNumColumn

                        .DataPropertyName = "GROUPNUM"
                        .HeaderText = "Group Number"
                        .ReadOnly = True

                    End With

                    With groupNameColumn

                        .DataPropertyName = "GROUPNAME"
                        .HeaderText = "Group Name"
                        .ReadOnly = True

                    End With

                    Dim coachingColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

                    With coachingColumn

                        .HeaderText = "RN Coaching"

                        .Items.AddRange({"Y", "N"})

                        .DataPropertyName = "COACHING"

                        .DisplayMember = .DataPropertyName
                        .ValueMember = .DisplayMember


                    End With

                    .AddRange({groupNumColumn, groupNameColumn, coachingColumn})

                End With

            End With
```

The grid is set up the way I want and it is displaying the all the data except all the comboBoxes have nothing selected. How do I get the comboBox to have a Y or N in them based on what was stored in that field.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: if so what type of column is COACHING in the db?  If it is Boolean, then "Y" and "N" are not direct conversions.  Rather than a combo, consider a checkbox.

Comment: The field type in the database is char and it is limited to one character. I was actually thinking of using a checkbox instead. @Plutonix any idea how I could use a checkbox to accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like the DB is a pseudo bool.  I'd change it if I could.

Comment: I totally agree with @Plutonix. Store the value as bit. It's always easier to format a value (for display) then parse (for storage).

Comment: the other problem, depending on the DB, is the chance that other characters get introduced.  you could try to convert it in SQL if you cant change the DB: something like `([Coaching]='Y') AS myCoaching` for MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are linked to the `DataSource` property. Whenever you change one of these properties, the data connection is reset. In other words: the items-collection is cleared.

Take your example for instance. The `String` class do not have a member named `COACHING`. It has properties like `Length` and `Chars` etc. So you cannot create a binding. Also, the items-collection accepts all kinds of objects.

You need to create and bind a custom data source. Here's an example using a `DataTable`:

```
Dim ynTable As New DataTable()

With ynTable
    .Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))
    .Rows.Add("Y")
    .Rows.Add("N")
    .AcceptChanges()
End With

With coachingColumn
    .HeaderText = "RN Coaching"
    .DataSource = ynTable
    .DataPropertyName = "COACHING"
    .DisplayMember = "Value"
    .ValueMember = "Value"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That has been driving me crazy all day. That worked like a charm. On a side note I was thinking about maybe using a check box instead of a combo box. Do you know how I could have it recognize Y as a True check and N for false?

Comment: @slister I'm pretty sure I've done that before but I don't recall how. Try google `parse` (push) and `format` (pull) + `DataGridViewCell`. If no luck, you can always ask a new question;)