# Use DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn with Y an N values instead of boolean values

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcheckboxcell

Hi I know this may sound a little silly but I want to use a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn on a field in a database that either contains 'Y', 'N', or blank values. I want the Y values to be checked and everything else to be unchecked.

I am using VB.NET by the way and any help with this would be appreciated. Also before anybody asks no I can't change the database field to boolean I have to just roll with it the way it is.

Comment: do you want to change `y` to true in assign datasource ah?

Comment: @Sathish yes that's what I want to do. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: did you try doing it in SQL (create a boolean expression based on whetehr the column is Y or N) ?

Comment: @Plutonix that is a good idea, but I am an SQL noob so how would that work exactly?

Comment: the syntax depends on the DB a little, `([Coaching]='Y') AS myCoaching ` will work for MS Access - you eval the actual column and "alias" the result as a boolean `myCoaching` ... or perhaps `([TableName.Coaching]='Y')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `IValueConverter`, something like this:

```
 public class YesNoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
 {

     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {

        return ((value as string).Equals("Y")) ? true : false;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
        return value;
     }
 }
```

In binding using converter, If you are using wpf, this how you bind it.

this just an example:

1. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project.converter"`

Under resources:

1. `<Grid.Resources>
      <local:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesNoToBooleanConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>`

In your column

1. `DataMemberBinding="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}"`

Comment: Where would I put that? Also how would I bind that to my column?

Comment: you can create a new class derived to : `IValueConverter` or use the existing class you have and derive it to `IValueConverter`

Comment: just convert it to vb.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

get the output of query is `boolean` like this

```
select case when column1="Y" then true else false end as column from table1
```

after that assign that `data source` in `datagridview`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment when [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453848/1842065) one of your previous questions: *I'm pretty sure I've done that before*. Well guess what, I had, and the solution is pretty simple.

The [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) class has two properties to help you.

- **[FalseValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.falsevalue(v=vs.110).aspx)**: Gets or sets the underlying value corresponding to a cell value of true, which appears as a checked box.
- **[TrueValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.truevalue(v=vs.110).aspx)**: Gets or sets the underlying value corresponding to a cell value of false, which appears as an unchecked box.

```vb
With Me.MyDataGridViewCheckBoxColumnInstance
    .FalseValue = "N"
    .TrueValue = "Y"
    .DataPropertyName = "MyYesNoDataColumnName"
End With
```